# Postgresql query generated by django works too slow

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a query like

```
    SELECT id 
    FROM   x 
    WHERE  is_valid = true 
        AND id IN (SELECT another_id 
                    FROM   y 
                    WHERE  ( other_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                            5, 6, 7, 8, 
                                            11, 16, 17, 18, 
                                            19, 20, 21, 22, 
                                            24, 26, 27, 28, 
                                            30, 31, 32, 34, 
                                            35, 36, 37, 38, 
                                            41, 43, 45, 46, 
                                            47, 48, 49, 50, 
                                            51, 52, 53, 54, 
                                            55, 56, 57, 58, 
                                            59, 60, 61, 63, 
                                            65, 67, 69, 72, 
                                            73, 76, 79, 80, 
                                            81, 82, 83, 84, 
                                            85, 86, 87, 88, 
                                            89, 90, 91, 92, 
                                            94, 95, 96, 97, 
                                            98, 100, 101, 102, 
                                            104, 105, 106, 107, 
                                            108, 109, 110, 112, 
                                            113, 114, 115, 116, 
                                            117, 118, 119, 121, 127 ) 
                            AND is_valid = true ));
```

I have analyzed the query in here https://explain.depesz.com/s/7ZWN.

I have index on is_valid fields and also has index together on other_id and is_valid. another_id and other_id fields are primary keys of Y table. X table has +900k and Y table has +15M entry in them.

Index declarations:

"y_is_valid_idx" btree (is_valid)

"y_other_id_is_valid_2344df8a_idx" btree (other_id, is_valid)

This query takes place at least 30sec to perform and it is a problem for API to response. I am using PostgreSql 9.6 and Django 1.11 for development. Can you suggest a way to faster this operation?

Comment: Start by running the query using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html
You can paste the output here to get some insights if you have trouble reading the output: https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: @Wolph done it and added result to the question.

Comment: It is tough to see why an index `on y (is_valid, other_id)` would not be used.  Are you sure you have a valid index on that?

Comment: You would expect the index on `y` to be used. If your queries are always similar you could create a partial index on `y(other_id)` with the `is_valid = true` filter. It's also possible that you need to increase the amount of statistics on the table. With a table thas has 15M rows the default of 100 might not be sufficient. Note that you want to set this specifically for that column/index, not the entire database: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/planner-stats.html

Comment: @jjanes added index declarations to the question

Comment: @Wolph I have added relative index declarations to the question. I believe I have that index you talk about.

Comment: @jjanes explain url is changed to show buffers.

Comment: Is the execution from a cold cache?  If you run this query often enough for it to be a problem, it seems like more of the index would be cached than is shown in "Buffers: shared hit=129 read=198378".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could perform this query faster about 5 secs but this will not solve the problem. running this type of heavy queries should be done before the request is made. you could do this by celery and perform your query in periodic times and then store your result in a model. then when request happens you have results already so you can return the result at the moment.